# MySQL - Deduct from two columns with a remainder

Tags: mysql, update

I have the following table:

```
Id,  balance, otherBalance
=============================
1,     100,      50
```

I would like to create an update query that receives a parameter 'amount' and does the following:
deduct from both balances columns the entire amount. Starting with the 'balance' column first, and only when it is depleted, deduct the remainder from the 'otherBalance'.

Examples

Executing update(98), will result in:

```
Id,  balance, otherBalance
=============================
1,     2,      50
```

Executing update(102), will result in:

```
Id,  balance, otherBalance
=============================
1,     0,      48
```

Executing update(151), will result in no change since both balances are less than the amount to be deducted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the variables to do the trick:

```
UPDATE table AS w
  JOIN amounts AS z ON z.w_Id = w.ID
   SET w.balance = IF( (@remainder := w.balance - z.amount) >= 0, @remainder, 0 )
     , w.otherBalance = IF( @remainder >= 0, w.otherBalance, w.otherBalance + @remainder )
;
```

Here I suppose that `amount` is fetched from the another table `amounts` and perform the mass update for all the rows at once.

If the `amount` is bigger than `balance`, then `@remainder` becomes negative therefore I've added it to the `otherBalance` instead of subtracting it.

Answer (score 0):

I thought the update could be simpler:

```
update following f
  join amounts a  on a.id = f.id
  set f.otherbalance = f.otherbalance + least(f.balance - a.amount, 0),
      f.balance = greatest(f.balance - a.amount, 0);
```

Check it out in this [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/583bb6/1)

Answer (score -1):

I had a go at this - thanks to a MySQL "feature" (albeit documented - see comments), it was tricky!

I was trying to solve this using pure SQL - it's relatively easy to do it in procedural code. But it can be done using SQL **IF** you have the update amount parameter in another table!

First I did this:

```
CREATE TABLE my_tab (my_id INTEGER, balance_1 UNSIGNED, balance_2 UNSIGNED);  
                           -- the reason for `UNSIGNED` is dealt with below!
INSERT INTO my_tab VALUES (1, 100, 50);

CREATE TABLE my_update_tab (update_amount INTEGER);
INSERT INTO my_update_tab VALUES (98);
```

And then I wrote the following SQL:
(check out the dbfiddle.com [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uq58jyg3vGoLW3fwBVEeUc/6))

```
UPDATE my_tab
SET 
  balance_2 =
    CASE
      WHEN (SELECT update_amount FROM my_update_tab) < balance_1 THEN balance_2 
      WHEN (SELECT update_amount FROM my_update_tab) > balance_1 THEN (balance_2 + balance_1 - (SELECT update_amount FROM my_update_tab))
  END,
  balance_1 = 
    CASE
      WHEN (SELECT update_amount FROM my_update_tab) < balance_1 THEN balance_1 - (SELECT update_amount FROM my_update_tab)
      WHEN (SELECT update_amount FROM my_update_tab) > balance_1 THEN 0
  END;
```

And then I ran:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tab;
```

To get the following (correct but see comments) result:

```
my_id   balance_1   balance_2
    1           2          50
```

Please see the comments to this post - there is a problem with MySQL (IMHO, still a bug). Thanks to ypercube for helping me complete this answer!

The MySQL Server doesn't appear to be aware that an `UPDATE` on one table even to 2 (or many) fields is normally a single transaction which is why balance_2 is updated before balance_1 - totally contrary to any sort of logic - this cost me a whole bunch of time!

PostgreSQL (again, surprise surprise) gets it right - see the dbfiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uq58jyg3vGoLW3fwBVEeUc/1)! (1, 2, 50) And [this one](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uq58jyg3vGoLW3fwBVEeUc/2) (1, 0, 10) - where amount is bigger than balance!

Maybe you should consider a decent RDBMS  (hint, PostgreSQL!) - one that obeys Codd's rules and other such logical concepts! :-) As a final point about MySQL - it doesn´t have `CHECK` constraints - so you have to use `UNSIGNED` so they can't go below zero - your transaction will fail if there´s any attempt to do so. The changes suggested by ypercube have been incorporated into the db-fiddle and this answer!

Comment: The problem is not transactional. It's that the update of the first column is done first, and then the update of the 2nd column "sees" the updated value of the first column - while it shouldn't. It should be seeing the old value. In other words, the updates of the columns happen one after the other and not all together.

Comment: If you do the update in reverse (column) oder, then it works: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bJHP6fbK9nkRevjuNzhSH/0

Comment: Yes - as I pointed out, it should be done à la PostgreSQL! A single update statement of two fields should be the way I expected it to work - what I consider to be one transaction is split into two by MySQL - and this is plain wrong!

Comment: It is wrong, true (or non-standard). But it is not 2 transactions. it's still one transaction ;)

Comment: The behaviour is documented in the [`UPDATE` statement docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html): *"The second assignment in the following statement sets `col2` to the current (updated) `col1` value, not the original `col1` value. The result is that `col1` and `col2` have the same value. **This behavior differs from standard SQL.**

`UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;`

**Single-table `UPDATE` assignments are generally evaluated from left to right.** For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that assignments are carried out in any particular order. "*

Comment: And feel free to put the info in your answer ;)

Comment: If I produced a documet an exam ¨proving¨ that PI was equal to 4, it still wouldn't be a good/valid piece work! I've put up the final db-fiddle - there's a bit of a trick with using UNSIGNED - you have to change the order of addition and subtraction (which are commutative so it doesn't matter). Answer and fiddle updated for the last time DG! Nice one spotting the reversing of the order of the updates!

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - OK - so it's a single transaction but it's therefore a dirty read or have I misunderstood what a dirty read is? It seems to me that the documentation confirms that that's what it is saying? p.s. thanks also for that link. Here's another doozie - "If you update a column that has been declared NOT NULL by setting to NULL, an error occurs if strict SQL mode is enabled; otherwise, the column is set to the implicit default value for the column data type and the warning count is incremented." Wow, it's even worse than I thought!